# How can I check whether 2 WPF Paths (with MatrixTransform applied) overlap

Tags: wpf, multi-touch, overlap

In my WPF multitouch application, I want to check whether a Path is overlapping another Path.

How can I do this? I have found different solutions on the Internet, but none is working, because of the combination of requirements:

- 2 Paths of irregular shape (so Bounds are not working: no Rect)
- On the Paths a MatrixTransform is applied (because of Manipulation events)
- The Paths can be rotated and scaled (using the MatrixTransform)
- The RenderTransformOrigin is 0.5, 0.5

How can I do this?

Example: in this example the blue and red star are overlapping, the red and the green are not.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.OtherWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="OtherWindow" Height="300" Width="300" >
<Canvas >
    <Path x:Name="path1" Data="M17,0 L23,11 34,13 27,21 28,32 18,24 8,30 9,19 0,11 13,11 z" Fill="#99FF0000" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,1,50,50"/>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="path2" Data="M17,0 L23,11 34,13 27,21 28,32 18,24 8,30 9,19 0,11 13,11 z" Fill="#990000FF" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.777817459305202,0.777817459305202,-0.777817459305202,0.777817459305202,35,45"/>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="path3" Data="M17,0 L23,11 34,13 27,21 28,32 18,24 8,30 9,19 0,11 13,11 z" Fill="#9900FF00" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.777817459305202,0.777817459305202,-0.777817459305202,0.777817459305202,82,55"/>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

How can I check this from code behind?

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable, you may use transformed geometries for Path.Data instead of (render-)transformed Paths (with the drawback of course that their stroke won't be scaled).
Once you use such transformed geometries, you can determine their mutual intersection by Geometry.FillContainsWithDetail, which gives you an enum value for the kind of intersection.

Your XAML might look like the following. Note that because Geometry does not have something like a transform origin, I modified your geometry so that the coordinate origin lies in its center. I also added the resulting offset to the MatrixTransform offset values.

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Name="redStar" Fill="#99FF0000" Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M0,-16 L6,-5 17,-3 10,5 11,16 1,8 -9,14 -8,3 -17,-5 -4,-5 z">
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,1,67,66"/>
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Name="blueStar" Fill="#990000FF" Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M0,-16 L6,-5 17,-3 10,5 11,16 1,8 -9,14 -8,3 -17,-5 -4,-5 z">
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.777817459305202,0.777817459305202,-0.777817459305202,0.777817459305202,52,61"/>
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Name="greenStar" Fill="#9900FF00" Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M0,-16 L6,-5 17,-3 10,5 11,16 1,8 -9,14 -8,3 -17,-5 -4,-5 z">
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.777817459305202,0.777817459305202,-0.777817459305202,0.777817459305202,99,71"/>
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

The following code will determine the intersections:

```
Geometry redGeometry = redStar.Data;
Geometry blueGeometry = blueStar.Data;
Geometry greenGeometry = greenStar.Data;

Trace.TraceInformation("red/blue intersection: {0}", redGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(blueGeometry));
Trace.TraceInformation("blue/green intersection: {0}", blueGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(greenGeometry));
Trace.TraceInformation("green/red intersection: {0}", greenGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(redGeometry));

redGeometry.Transform = new MatrixTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 70, 90);

Trace.TraceInformation("red/blue intersection: {0}", redGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(blueGeometry));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested it and it works. However, when I try to update the transformation in code (by: redGeometry.Transform = new MatrixTransform(......)), the object is transformed on the screen correctly, but the FillContainsWithDetail doesn't return a correct value. Any ideas?

Comment: See changed answer, Data instead of RenderedGeometry should work.

Comment: Jim, does it work as you expect if you change frm RenderedGeometry to Data? If yes, consider accepting the answer by clicking the  accept tick.